# Mute all sounds by elements with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I would like to know how to mute all audio within a specific div class. This is mainly to mute ads playing unexpected videos or commercials on my site. I have the all of the ads under the div class "muted" so I would like to mute those divs but still allow for YouTube videos (obviously outside the divs) to play the audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be impossible. Most advertising networks run advertisements through iframes. Since the documents contained in these frames will be hosted on a different domain, scripts running on your domain cannot access them. Additionally, most advertisements using sound are likely to be playing those sounds using Flash, which I don't think you can mute or prevent from autoplaying from Javascript at all, short of removing them entirely (which would probably break your agreement with the advertising network).

Your best option is likely going to be to find a better advertising network that doesn't run ads with autoplay sound / video.

Comment: He's right. You need to take control of your website's content. If you don't want ads that play sporadic sounds, then remove those ads. If you're not in direct control of the ads, and are trying to be a hooligan with the webspace somebody's given you, then I suppose you could have a script.. destroy the ads' iframes.

Comment: Ive decided to listen to better judgement and just remove those ads..  I would prefer the better user experience..  Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

This will mute any `<audio>` or `<video>` elements inside every element with a class of `muted`:

```
$(function(){
  $('.muted').find('audio, video').each(function(){
    this.volume = 0;
  });
});
```

Here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/iYiWaPi/edit

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { $(".muted").muted = true; });
```

Comment: You can't set an attribute like that on a jQuery collection. `$(".muted").attr("muted", true)` is a little closer, but even that would only work on HTML5 audio / video, which very few advertisers use.